# Module Federation shared library loading half from remote/ half from host?

Tags: webpack, shared-libraries, webpack-module-federation

I have a `StylesLibrary` exporting two components for example button and form.

They are imported like `StylesLibrary/button` and `StylesLibrary/form`

Host using `StylesLibrary` v1.0.0 (Host uses both button and form)

Remote using `StylesLibrary` v1.0.1 (remote using only button)

I am sharing the package like:

```
shared: {
    "StylesLibrary/": {requiredVersion: deps["StylesLibrary"]} //deps is package.json
}
```

In this case if I am sharing the `StylesLibrary` b/w host and remote, the button component is loaded from remote (since it has higher version?) and form component is loaded from host(cause it is not being used in remote I think).

Is this expected from how `shared` API? How can we force all the sub components of the library (form/ button) to be loaded and have same version (both either 1.0.0 or 1.0.1)?